# rails google oauth2 not working on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

In rails application we use google authentication for internal users.
it works great on localhost and until last week also on our server.
As of this weekend I'm getting this error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/auth/google_oauth2"):
```

Routes:

```
    require 'sidekiq/web'
    require_relative '../lib/superuser_constraint'
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq', :constraints => SuperuserConstraint.new
    get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    
    get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#omniauth'

    root 'home#index'
```

Initializer:

```
#config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :google_oauth2, Rails.application.credentials[:google_authentication][:client_id],Rails.application.credentials[:google_authentication][:client_secret], skip_jwt: true
end
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

does anyone know why this is happening? I didn't make any changes to the application.

Comment: I understand you said no changes, but can you post your routes?